# installing a newer version of tcl with idle

Tags: python, tcl, python-idle

I know that there is a previous link posted here
[IDLE warns against an old TCL version even though I've installed a newer version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129498/idle-warns-against-an-old-tcl-version-even-though-ive-installed-a-newer-version)

essentially, i've installed python but it gave me a warning about an out of date activetcl. I download and install it but idle is not able to detect the new install

im wondering how i can change the path in idle after i've installed a newer version. Or am I doing something entirely wrong

Answer (score 0):

**To view the path include in your current PATH variable inside idle do**

```
import sys
sys.path
```

The above will give you the list of paths in the PATH variable , Look for the path of the tcl included, whether its a new or older version,if older version remove the older and include the new version

**To add a Path do,**

```
sys.path.append(your path)
```

**To remove a path from the list**

```
sys.path.remove(your path)
```