# Replace unstable Tcl/Tk on native python

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.5 and recently I've started with Tkinter and tk. However, whenever I start up IDLE, I get this:

```
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.

>>>
```

I'm looking at installing a new version of Tkinter with tcl/tk but I'm not sure if that could ruin my system's performance. If I can install another version, where should I install it and which version?

This is what it says at the link it provides me:

If you are using OS X 10.9 or later and a Python from a python.org 64-bit/32-bit installer, application windows may not update properly due to a Tk problem. Install the latest ActiveTcl 8.5.17.0 if possible. (Also, a critical OS X 10.9 problem that could cause Python to crash when used interactively has been fixed as of the 3.4.0, 3.3.3, and 2.7.6 installers.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129498/idle-warns-against-an-old-tcl-version-even-though-ive-installed-a-newer-version

Comment: Thanks. That gives me some insight, but part of that solution would require me to reinstall python. I don't think I can do that since python is basically a necessity on Mac OS X.

Comment: yes, I would not recommend it but the first part seems to suggest you cannot change it as it is done when python is compiled

Comment: So, in other words, I'm stuck with what I have... Great.

Comment: did you actually try installing ActiveTcl 8.5.17.0?

Comment: In fact, I have. I guess I kind of forgot to include that I did. I should probably change my question a little bit. Except for when I did install that version, I had gotten many errors for some reason.

Comment: did you get errors installing 8.5.17.0?

Comment: Yep, Don't remember what they were though (it was a while back).

Comment: try reinstalling and add the errors, a last  alternative would be installing  a second python in /usr/local.

Comment: Sure. I'm already in the process of retrying the installation right now :)

Comment: Actually, solved. This time, it didn't give me any errors. IDLE is working fine. However, I just have one more question, I feel as if it changed some of the default settings in Idle, including the font and font size. Do you know what the defaults are (the fonts that it changed to are really ugly and I want the old ones back).

Comment: I would probably  just reinstall but you can change the font in options>configure idle. The default size  on ubuntu is 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, with some help from Padraic Cunningham, I was able to install a functioning version of  Tkinter. You need to get ActiveTcl 8.5.17.0 if you have the buggy Apple version 8.5.9. The package was very simple, just be careful of your computer's security settings as the version doesn't look to be signed (it's developer appears as unknown). Otherwise, it should do most of the work for you. On a side note, make sure that you know your original font style and size, so that you can change it back when the installer does (likely on accident).