# Warning for Tcl/Tk version 8.5.9 in python IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, activetcl

I am using the python 3.5.2 distribution from `brew install python3` and when I start IDLE I receive the following error message:

```
WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.
```

After following python.org's [recommendation](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) for which version of ActiveTcl, I then installed 8.5.18.

Next, following the information in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129498/idle-warns-against-an-old-tcl-version-even-though-ive-installed-a-newer-version), I uninstalled python3 using `brew uninstall python3` and re-installed using `brew install python3`. Finally, I restarted my mac (macOS 10.12)

However, I am still seeing the same error when I open IDLE. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

Comment: I wonder if using `brew` also deals with the tcl part itself so it doesn't use the newer version, hard to rule that aspect out.  I do know that the [function that makes that error message](https://github.com/tadhgmister/cpython/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/macosx.py#L70) does say that `8.5.9` can crash unexpectedly but isn't as bad as `8.5.7` I also know that I never figured this out for myself. :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried uninstalling/installing from python.org and homebrew many times and eventually this method worked for me:

```
brew remove python3
brew install homebrew/dupes/tcl-tk
brew install python3 --with-tcl-tk
brew linkapps python3
```