# stuck, just downloaded python and tried to run IDLE but this happened

Tags: python, macos

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.
```

I'm working with a mac on os version 10.12.2 very new to coding and just started working on a book called, "automating the boring stuff with python." This was what prompted me to down load python. once down loaded I'm supposed to run Idle and play with it but its not letting me even type a thing. Any help? edit:
so, this is what the book says i should be looking at and doing in the interactive shell....The Interactive Shell
No matter which operating system you’re running, the IDLE window that  rst appears should be mostly blank except for text that looks something like this:
             Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64
             bit (AMD64)] on win32Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more
             information.

> > >
> >     This window is called the interactive shell. A shell is a program that lets you type instructions into the computer, much like the Terminal or Command Prompt on OS X and Windows, respectively. Python’s interactive shell lets you enter instructions for the Python interpreter software to run. The com- puter reads the instructions you enter and runs them immediately.
> >     For example, enter the following into the interactive shell next to the >>> prompt:
> >
> > > print('Hello world!')
> > >       After you type that line and press enter, the interactive shell should
> > >       display this in response:
> > >       print('Hello world!') Hello world!

Comment: maybe related to: [IDLE warns against an old TCL version even though I've installed a newer version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129498/idle-warns-against-an-old-tcl-version-even-though-ive-installed-a-newer-version)

Comment: Did you download python from http://www.python.org/ ? Looks like this is currently [a known bug with Apple 8.5.9](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) which suggests to use a `current python.org installer that links with ActiveTcl 8.5.18.0 or by using a third-party distribution of Python that does not use Apple 8.5.9 Tk. This is an Aqua Cocoa Tk.`

Comment: i downloaded from http://python.org/downloads/. just as the book suggested.  thanks downshift, any idea were i can get the aqua coco tk?

Comment: sure, it should be available here http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads